# Вывод Div'а только на одной странице по условию

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Помогите решить задачу. 
Есть код, который выводит описание к категории

```
    <div class="category_description">
        <?php echo $this->category->category_description ; ?>
    </div>
```

Категории имеют пагинацию типа:

- mysite.com/category
- mysite.com/category?start9
- mysite.com/category?start18
- и т.д.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как задать условие, чтобы данный див выводился только на первых страницах категорий: **mysite.com/category**, **mysite.com/category2**, **mysite.com/tag4** и т.п.
Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

```
if($_GET['foo'] == 'category' || $_GET['foo'] == 'category2' || $_GET['foo'] == 'tag2'){
   print '<div class="category_description">'. $this->category->category_description .'</div>';
}
```

попробуйте так

*вместо foo вставьте индекс массива который используется в вашем коде

Comment: Спасибо. Но вы немного неверно меня поняли! Нужно создать условие, которое будет выводить блок только на перво странице пагинации. Категорий может быть N-ое кол-во и у них может быть разный урл. Нужно создать условие которое не будет выводить блок при наличии ?start. наверное так